# Express module not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I installed the express module using npm and -g option. The command shows up in the bash browser but in the node terminal, it shows this error.

```
require.resolve('express')
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:23:19)
    at repl:1:9
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:95:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:211:10)
```

What am I doing wrong?
I also installed express-generator but still wouldn't do

My `.bashrc` file has these entries:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in the directory where you have placed package.json

```
npm install express --save
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked .. But do I have to do this everytime I create a new node app

Comment: You have to do this for each node app that uses the `express` module.

Comment: Yes you have to do it everytime you create a new app.